# Probability of Choosing a Card from a Deck

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There were quite a few deck of cards probability problems and I went through a few but couldn't find anything close so please forgive me if this is a repeat.

The question is as follows:

> Two cards are chosen without replacement at random from a standard 52-card deck. What is
>   the probability that
>   (b) the first card is a heart and the second card is a 10?

We will be dividing by C(52,2) since we're choosing two cards from a deck of 52. This quantity is 1326.

Our first choice must be a heart so we have C(13,1) since there are 13 hearts in a deck and we're choosing one.

Second choice must be a 10 so we need C(4,1)
Thus, we get $\frac{C(13,1)C(4,1)}{C(52,2)}$ = 3.92%

Is my logic correct?

Thanks.

Comment: What if you first chose the 10 of hearts?

Comment: Apart from the little glitch about the $\heartsuit 10$, there is a bigger problem. When we use counting to calculate probabilities, top and bottom must count the **same kind** of thing. Your denominator counts **hands**, while your numerator counts **ordered** pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can still make your counting-based approach work by considering two disjoint cases: either the first card is 10 of hearts or not.

If the first card is 10 of hearts, then there are only three 10's remaining in the deck, for a total of $1 \cdot 3 = 3$ outcomes in this case.

If the first card is any of the other twelve hearts, then all four 10's remain in the deck, for a total of $12 \cdot 4 = 48$ outcomes in this case.

Taken together, we find the probability is
$$
\frac{3 + 48}{52 \cdot 51} = \frac{1}{52} \approx 1.92\%.
$$

As André points out in the comments, the denominator is $52 \cdot 51$ rather than $C(52,2)$ since you are distinguishing between the first card and the second card (i.e. you are counting ordered pairs).

Answer (score 4):

The way that I would approach this question is to approach the two events separately and then multiply their probabilities.

So first we try to find the probability of choosing a heart out of the deck, this is pretty obvious as there are only $4$ suits, and therefore:

$$P(\text{Heart})=\frac{1}{4}$$

Next we look at the probability of choosing a $10$ considering that we've just taken a heart of unknown value out of the deck:

$$\begin{align}P(10\mid \text{Heart already taken})&=P(10\text{ of Hearts removed})P(10 \mid 10\text{ of Hearts removed}) \\ &+ P(10\text{ of Hearts not removed})P(10\mid 10\text{ of Hearts not removed})\\ 
&= \frac{1}{13}\times\frac{3}{51}+\frac{12}{13}\times\frac{4}{51}=\frac{1}{13}\end{align}$$

We then multiply the two probabilities together to get:

$$\begin{align}P(\text{Heart followed by a }10)&=P(\text{Heart})P(10\mid \text{Heart already taken}) \\ &= \frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{13}=\frac{1}{52}\approx1.92\% \end{align}$$

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the help! Have a great day.

Comment: This validates that taking a heart does not change the probability that the second card is a $10$ since there are the same fraction of $10$'s among the hearts as among the non-hearts.